# How to prevent nginx from creating index.html on startup

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm using the latest official [nginx docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/).

Whenever I start the container, two files are created in `/usr/share/nginx/html`

```
root@ba65db04a18f:/# ls -la /usr/share/nginx/html   
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 28 15:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 23 00:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  537 May 30 13:03 50x.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  612 May 30 13:03 index.html
```

How do I prevent these files from being created?

The commands I'm using to launch the container are:

```
docker volume create static
docker run -it --rm --name nginx -v static:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

The default configuration file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) is:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And there is one file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` called default.conf which has the contents:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

I've tried overwriting this `default.conf` file with a blank file by launching the container with the command:

```
docker volume rm static
docker volume create static
docker run -it --rm --name nginx -v static:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -v /path/on/host/to/blank/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx
```

But nginx still creates `index.html` and `50x.html`. How do I get it to stop?

Comment: Nginx does not create these files. They are in docker image https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/Dockerfile#L101-L102

Comment: @AlexeyTen Aha I've been searching for that for hours! So I'll probably have to extend the image and remove them. Dang, I was trying to figure out a way to do it without having to write my own Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nginx docker image is responsible for the `index.html` and `50x.html` files:

https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/48a4c531fc4bfa80d4270f20a67e2e958856860c/stable/alpine/Dockerfile#L101-L102

To prevent them from being created it would be necessary to extend the official nginx docker image and remove the files.

Alternatively it should also be possible to alter the `CMD` used to start the container so that it removes the files before starting the nginx process.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to docker-compose.yml

```
  nginx-afterstart:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - folder:/folder
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    restart: "no"
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "ls -al /folder/ && sleep 10 && rm /folder/*.html && ls -al /folder/"]
```

I know this thread is old, but it's a top search result. :P